# Network Adapter - CTRL EVENT SCAN FAILED (unstable hardware)

Tags: networking, hardware

I am using Manjaro Linux over an old HP Laptop (HP Pavilion G6 2298SE). This Laptop has following (Ralink) Network Adapter:

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

The problem is that I am frequently being disconnected from internet (4-5 times a day). When this happens then the NetworkManager shows no wireless connection in its list. After disconnection, the "lspci", "ip" and "lshw" show the Network Adapter in their results.

"lspci" result after disconnection:

```
[user:pc:~]lspci | grep -i wireless
    07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

"ip" result after disconnection:

```
[user:pc:~]ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:22:33:44:55:66 brd 11:22:33:44:55:66
3: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

"lshw" result after disconnection. it shows it as "Disabled":

```
[user:pc:~]lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 11:22:33:44:55:66
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.4.135-1-MANJARO firmware=0.40 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:c3500000-c350ffff
```

However, "ifconfig" does not show the Network Adapter in its result:

```
[user:pc:~]ifconfig
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 11:22:33:44:55:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 555  bytes 46097 (45.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 555  bytes 46097 (45.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And "journalctl -xe" shows following messages at the instance of disconnection:

```
Aug 07 16:18:36 pc wpa_supplicant[860]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=11:22:33:44:55:66 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Aug 07 16:18:36 pc wpa_supplicant[860]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Aug 07 16:18:36 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335116.4861] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Aug 07 16:18:36 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335116.6025] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 07 16:18:51 pc NetworkManager[805]: <warn>  [1628335131.8396] device (wlo1): link timed out.
Aug 07 16:18:51 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335131.8400] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 07 16:18:51 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335131.8404] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc avahi-daemon[801]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc avahi-daemon[801]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address 1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666.
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc avahi-daemon[801]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc avahi-daemon[801]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.10.100.
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc avahi-daemon[801]: Withdrawing address record for 1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666 on wlo1.
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335133.4017] device (wlo1): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 54:CA:64:85:34:E2 (scanning)
Aug 07 16:18:53 pc avahi-daemon[801]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.10.100 on wlo1.
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc kernel: ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_csr_ready: Error - Unstable hardware
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc NetworkManager[805]: <warn>  [1628335134.4128] platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: failure changing link: failure 16 (Device or resource busy)
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc NetworkManager[805]: <warn>  [1628335134.4131] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'Home'
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc wpa_supplicant[860]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc dbus-daemon[803]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=805 comm="/usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335134.4144] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> interface_disabled
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc NetworkManager[805]: <info>  [1628335134.4147] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 07 16:18:54 pc systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
```

"ip" command shows that the Network Adapter is "DOWN", so if I try to bring it up then it gives following error:

```
[user:pc:~]sudo ip link set down wlo1 && sudo ip link set up wlo1
    RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

Few months back, this used to happen rarely (once a week or bi-weekly), but now the problem is more frequent (4-5 times a day). In order to fix it, I have to reboot my Laptop then the Network Adapter again started to work fine (for a while).
So, the question is that: Is my Network Adapter dying? or Is there any other problem with it (driver, power management etc.)?
Can you help me in this regard?